# Log for ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ilogger

There is a TraceIdentifier for one request in asp.net, how to write such an id into logs or some other way automatic. Thx

Request.HttpContext.TraceIdentifier

my purpose can collect all the log messages for one request

Comment: And ILogger is an abstraction. Which concrete library do you use for logging?

Comment: Sumlogic. and I also hope to find a universal way to log a such case. Thx

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I haven't found solutions with Illogger.But there is a way to do it with Serilog.
Install nugetpackage
`Serilog`
`Serilog.AspNetCore`
`Serilog.Sinks.Console`   //install if log to console
`Serilog.Sinks.File`      //install if log to file
`SumoLogic.Logging.Serilog`
`Serilog.Enrichers.GloabalLogContext`

in Program.cs add

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .Enrich.FromGlobalLogContext()         //for pushing httpcontext properties later
    .WriteTo.Console(new JsonFormatter())              //write to console
    .WriteTo.File(new JsonFormatter(), "mylog.json")    //write to file 
    .WriteTo.BufferedSumoLogic(new Uri("https://collectors.us2.sumologic.com/receiver/v1/http/your_endpoint_here=="), formatter: new JsonFormatter())            //send to sumologic
    .CreateLogger();
```

in controller method

```
    [ApiController]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {

        [HttpGet("test")]
        public void test()
        {
            GlobalLogContext.PushProperty("TraceIdentifier", Request.HttpContext.TraceIdentifier);   
            Log.Information("hello");
            Log.Information("bye");

        }
    }
```

output
[image]
A general way to add additional property in serilog is when config in program.cs  use  `.Enrich.WithProperty(key,value)` , but because we cannot use  httpcontext in program.cs so we use pushproperty to reconfig in method.
-------------------------------------------orignal answer------------------------------------------------
Install nuget package `SumoLogic.Logging.AspNetCore`

```
    [ApiController]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        ILogger logger = LoggerFactory.Create(config =>
        {
            config.AddConsole();    //to see in console window
            config.AddSumoLogic(      //send log to sumologic
                new LoggerOptions
                {
                    Uri = "https://collectors.us2.sumologic.com/receiver/v1/http/your_endpoint_here=="
                }
            );
        }).CreateLogger<ValuesController>();

        [HttpGet("test")]
        public void test()
        {
            logger.LogInformation(Request.HttpContext.TraceIdentifier);
        }
    }
```

I just create a instance directly, you can also defube `_logger` by inject.

Comment: Thanks. I hope that Request.HttpContext.TraceIdentifier(or some other identifier for one web request) can be configured for ILogger, so that when we take logger.LogInformation("Hello world!"), we can find the value of "Request.HttpContext.TraceIdentifier" in the log message. Thx

Comment: @kevin I didn't see there's good way to add additonal information use ilogger, but there are something you can do with serilog, Is that all right?

Comment: @Kevin I have modify the answer , you can check.

Comment: Thanks, @Qiang Fu, This behavior is indeed what I need.